# how to localize white markings for an image taken under different light conditions

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am having two pictures of the same road taken during different light conditions as shown next

[image]
The first picture is taken in evening and the second one during daylight. I have to write one general code which determines the white lane marks of the road for both ligh scenerios. I have tried ways like sobel edge detection, connected components and have also tried to find the white lane marks by applying conditions on white pixel values.But the algorithm which works on the first picture doesnot work on the second one. Please guide me

Comment: This cannot be answered. You need to do more research on the task, pick an specific point that is not working, and then ask about that.

Answer (score 3):

This is bound to fail since there are so many different conditions from which these pictures could be taken at, but here goes some steps that works for these ones. They might be more useful together with other techniques, which are fully dependent on the task you are doing.

Start with a morphological gradient thicker than usual (with a 5x5 flat structuring element, for example) using `max(R, G, B)` (this is equivalent to converting your input to the HSB colorspace and picking the channel `B` there). This assumes the markings are white, like the question's title suggests, which will likely be highlighted by this step.

Binarize the current image at a low threshold, since the markings are not that significant in the input, followed by a morphological closing and a thinning. Here, this closing operation is playing the role of a cheap component closing as well a hole filling per component. Thinning will help distinguishing lines that you might be after from those that you certainly are not.

Now you can measure the components to attempt to select the ones you are after. Measurements such pixel count and those involving convex hull are interesting. From the later you can extract the mean caliper diameter, which for line segments will give a value closer to the pixel count.

Here are the individual results, as well the final result:

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

The wrong line segment can be eliminated by considering how "non-white" it is, as well using more problem-specific information such as the expected angle for these segments.

Comment: I don't think so question is unclear. As I have mentioned above that I have tried some ways to tackle the light issues but they are not working properly. I had done a little work on morphological operations but I don't know exactly how to use them for my problem. According to the answer given by mmgp, it seems a solution to my problem. Can you please be a bit more explicit as it may resolve the issue and the purpose of asking the question will be fulfilled.

Comment: @sahil The question is not unclear, it is just overly broad. Its own title suggests you are working with images "taken under different light conditions", and that is too broad already. My answer might be too simplistic for other scenarios, but if it helped you then that is perfectly fine.

Comment: Sir I actually tried this method which you have mentioned but the issue could not be resolved the way you have resolved above.I tried the following code: I = imread('road1.jpg');
hsv = rgb2hsv(imcomplement(I));
I1 = hsv(:,:,3);                %# work with V channel
figure 
imshow(I1)
I2 = im2bw(I1, 0.25);
figure 
imshow(I2)
I3 = bwmorph(I2, 'thin');
figure
imshow(I3)
I4 = bwmorph(I3, 'spur', 7);
figure
imshow(I4)
I5 = imdilate(I4, strel([1 1 1 1 1]));
figure
imshow(I5)                                                             Kindly correct me with the code.

Comment: @sahil you skipped the thick morphological gradient, why ? Maybe that part of the answer is unclear. What you need to do is apply this operator on your `V` channel. What you are doing is taking the `V` channel as the result, without applying any operator, that is incorrect.

Comment: Can you kindly guide me with the correct syntax.

Comment: @sahil you could create an structuring element using `se = strel('square', 5);` and then doing `g = imdilate(l1, se) - imerode(l1, se)`.

Comment: Sir I got the hint from your previous comment. I have done it already.Now my code is; img = imread('newroad1.jpg');
hsv = rgb2hsv(img);
I1 = hsv(:,:,3);
se = strel('square',5);
mgrad = imdilate(I1, se) - imerode(I1, se);
I=im2bw(mgrad,graythresh(mgrad));
BW1=bwmorph(I,'close');
BW2 = bwmorph(BW1,'thin',inf);
figure,imshow(BW2) But I am not getting the second result. What magic you have used to get this result:) please guide me.

Comment: Sir your suggestion could give me the solution to my problem.

Comment: @sahil `im2bw(a, graythresh(x))` binarizes according to Otsu, which is unwanted here. Use a low threshold, for example, try with `I = im2bw(mgrad, 0.1);`.

Answer (score 0):

Lane detection is a well-studied topic. I will give you name of some papers to start off with, but this is by no means a comprehensive list. You should do more literature survey. If you are doing this for a course project, then just understand the core idea and try to implement that, otherwise, you will have to understand the papers fully.

1. Robust lane detection and tracking in challenging scenarios
2. Real-time detection of lane markers in urban streets
3. Improved vision-based lane tracker performance using vehicle localizationImproved vision-based lane tracker performance using vehicle localization

Code for 3 is also available, but unless and until you understand the code without practcig file.